# Integration ok in wolfram alpha but not R or Matlab, what gives?

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

Here is a link to wolfram alpha where a function is integrated from -inf to inf and we get the result ≈ -0.65.

[Link to wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20from%20-inf%20to%20inf%20(1-e%5E(-x))*(1%2F(sqrt(2*pi)))%20*%20e%5E(-(x%5E2)%2F2))

I am trying to do this in R and Matlab but it seems divergent and the result is NaN.

Matlab code:

```
g = @(x) (1-exp(-x)).*(1/(sqrt(2*pi))) .* exp(-(x.^2)/2);
integral(g,-inf, inf)
```

Error message:

```
Warning: Infinite or Not-a-Number value encountered.
```

R code:

```
f = function(x) (1-exp(-x))*(1/(sqrt(2*pi))) * exp(-(x^2)/2) 
U = integrate(f4, -Inf, Inf)
```

Error message:

```
Error in integrate(f4, -Inf, Inf) : non-finite function value
```

I've also tried to use the dnorm function in R (since the (1/(sqrt(2*pi))) * exp(-(x^2)/2)) is a normal curve with mean = 0, and sd = 1 but it is not working either.

```
f_dnorm = function(x) (1-exp(-x))*dnorm(x, mean = 0, sd = 1)
U_dnorm = integrate(f_dnorm, -Inf, Inf)
```

Error message: same as in previous case.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: It seems to me that you have a 0 times infinity type behavior as you go to $-\infty$. You could remove that with an algebraic simplification (summing the exponents in the exp terms). Alternately you could just cut off the lower limit somewhere to avoid the problem at the cost of some error.

Comment: I see. I will try to simplify it algebraically.

Comment: To replicate Wolfram Alpha use Matlab's [Symbolic Math toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/): `syms x;` `g=(1-exp(-x))*exp(-(x^2)/2)/sqrt(2*sym(pi));` `int(g,-Inf,Inf)`. This returns `1-exp(1/2)`, which is equivalent Wolfram Alpha's $1-\sqrt{e}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error probably happens while R and MATLAB try to numerically calculate the integral, while Wolfram Alpha does it symbollically and avoids overflow issues.

You did nothing wrong, you just found a limitation of numeric integration.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, because the function looks very well-behaved. The trapezium rule gets the value correct without much effort to six decimal places on $[-5,5]$.

Comment: Ok, it works if I integrate it in a smaller interval. The approximation will be good enough so will go for that.